# Issue in printing code in R taken from python

Tags: r

I am trying to print the python string in R with the below code, but not able to . Can anyone please help

```
py_run_string("print(Hello)")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotation marks around `Hello`

`reticulate::py_run_string("print('Hello')")`